# How to sync two tree structures?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-structures, tree, windows-services

I have a web application (ASP .NET application) hosted on a web server (IIS) and a client desktop application (Windows Service). The web application has a tree structure in database tables. So for e.g. there is a table [Tree] with columns (NodeId, NodeName, ParentNodeId). So you have a recursive tree structure.
On the client side there is a folder structure corresponding to the server tree structure. So for e.g. if you have following entries in the Tree table on server side

```
NodeId NodeName ParentNodeId
------ -------- ------------
1       Folder1  NULL
2       Folder2   1
3       Folder3   1
```

Then you have a folder structure on the client side like

```
Folder1 > Folder2
Folder1 > Folder3
```

Now whenever the tree structure is updated on the server I need to update the folder structure on the client. For this I have a web service that the client calls at a fixed interval and fetches the entire tree structure and then updates the folder structure accordingly. However sending the entire tree structure on every call seems inefficient to me.

Is there any other approach that is efficient that can be used to solve this problem ? Like using a different data structure to store the hierarchy

**Edit 1:**
At the server side there can be any change like for e.g. moving/copying an entire node subset to a new parent node or deleting the entire node subset

Comment: You can send information about what has changed since a given time; sending a diff, rather than the entire data set, is applicable regardless of the structure of that data.

Comment: Another option is to remember sequence of modification operations (node added, node remove, node updated) that were applied to tree and feed that to clients so they can replicate them on their end.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure seems like a standard parent-child relationship so at first glance I don't see an issue with it.

You can use a real-time approach via [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead of the fixed interval approach you are currently using.

To avoid pulling down the entire node structure, you can put a flag on your table noting whether the row is new / has been updated or put some timestamp columns on your table. You will have to include any filters in your sql and ensure any columns you filter on are indexed.